# how to resume to correct layer after app terminates (cocos2d)

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, resume

Hi i need help with this code. In my game i have main layer which has menu button for options and game level.
And I have a game layer to play the game.

When I terminated the app by clicking the home button and i relaunch the game again,it starts in the correct spot i left.

My questions is when i terminate in the game layer i want to launch a resume/pause layer when it resumes, and when i terminate the game in the main layer i dont want to launch resume/pause layer. how can i do that?

currently here is my code.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:[PauseScene scene]];
}
```

I hope someone can help me coz im still learning on ios programming

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    if (nil != [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene]) {
        // make sure we have a scene to release, 
        // since this method is invoked on start up, too
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] popScene];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
    }
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:[PauseScene scene]];
    // pause CCDirector, so we can keep any scheduled events for later
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
}
```